# add background color over owl carousel image

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

<del>I'm using [jQuery Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)</del> and I've created an image slider in which I want to add a background color over the slider image.

**Note from 2019**: http://owlgraphic.com redirects to malicious site now.

Here's the markup:

```
 <!-- HEADER-02 CONTENT -->
<div class="header-02-sub">

<!-- SLIDER STARTS HERE -->
<div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x700" alt="The Last of us">
            <div class="caption">

             <h1>SOME TITLE HERE</h1>

            </div>               
          </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x700" alt="The Last of us">
             <div class="caption">

             <h1>SOME TITLE HERE</h1>

            </div>          
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x700" alt="The Last of us">
            <div class="caption">

             <h1>SOME TITLE HERE</h1>

            </div>     
          </div>

        </div>
  <!-- SLIDER ENDS HERE -->      


 </div>

 <!-- END HEADER-02 CONTENT -->
```

I've tied adding this CSS :

```
.header-02-sub {
background-color:red;
z-index:9999999;
witdth:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

I've tried also adding this code to the `#owl-slider` parent or `.item` and none of these works.

Here's a **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/boxim/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

Any suggestions on how can I add a background color over the slide image ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an absolutely positioned DIV (we'll call it `.overlay`) into the `.item` element and then mark-up this new DIV with

```
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1600px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**Update:**

If your page is responsive, add `position: relative` to `.item` and then change `.overlay` height and width to 100%

```
.item{
  position: relative;
}
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[New JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pekumeje/1/edit)

Comment: this works, but I have a small problem, the images are responsive so I need a way to make the overlay cover the image regardless the screen resolution

Comment: Use jquery to get the image height and width and set the overlay's height and width respectively